# Run VSTS Build/Release Task only when previous task errors

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to create a Visual Studio Team Services Extension Task for my builds and releases. I need a task that will send out an alert to another system if a previous task (including the default build/test/publish/etc.) fails.

I have already created the task to send the alert. However I do not see a way to kick off the task only if my build fails.

Is there a way in VSTS to run a task if a previous task fails, but not run it if all other tasks were successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in feature.

*But* you can use the "Rollback" task from the Release Management Utilities to run a powershell script on failure.

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to select a running condition for all tasks with the following possible values:

- Only when all previous tasks have succeeded
- Even if a previous task has failed, unless the build was canceled
- Even if a previous task has failed, even if the build was canceled
- Only when a previous task has failed
- Custom conditions

[image: "Only when a previous task has failed" condition selected]

**EDIT:**
It is currently part of a preview, you can enable it through the "Preview features" menu after you click on your profile click on VSTS:
[image: Profile menu]

And activate the "New Build Editor":
[image: Preview features menu]

Comment: What version of TFS online is this for?  I do not see this as an option.

Comment: I forgot to said that it is part of a preview, you can enable it through the "Preview features" menu after you click on your profile click on VSTS and activate "New Build Editor".